# How Can I Search for a Character in a String in Vim Script

Tags: string, function, if-statement, search, vim

I am writing a function in Vim script that takes one argument. It could be either a comma separated list of numbers (e.g. `1,2,3`), or a range of numbers (e.g. `1-3`). I want to check if the second character in the argument is a `-` symbol so that I can know that it is a range of numbers. Here is code:

```
function! MyFunction(...)
    if second_char(a:1) == '-'
        echo "Hyphen"
    else
        echo "Comma"
    endif
endfunction

command -nargs=* MyFunction call MyFunction(<f-args>)
```

I read the documentation for the `search` function but it is honestly really confusing.

Comment: Let's see your actual code.

Comment: I don't have "actual code", which is why I gave pseudo-code. I would like to check if the hyphen (`-`) character is used using an `if` statement.

Comment: You would need actual code to make this an actual programming question. You need to put more effort into this.

Comment: Someone suspiciously deleted my comment. Anyways, since you weren't helpful, I figured it out on my own. I will answer my own question.

Comment: Congratulations! "I figured it out on my own" was the point all along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's really as simple as using brackets. Here is an example, where MY_STRING is the string you're using:

```
if MY_STRING[1] == '-'
    echo "Hyphen"
else
    echo "Comma"
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to assure the argument is correct.

Using the second character is quite fragile because your numbers can assume values greater than 9, see the example below:

```
" let s:myVar = "10,20,30"
let s:myVar = "50-55"

if s:myVar =~ '\d\+,\d\+'
  echo "are comma separated values"
elseif s:myVar =~ '\d\+-\d\+'
  echo "is a range"
else
  echo "the argument is invalid"
endif
```